# I want to format Arabic speech in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, arabic, kivymd, textinput

I have this code
File .py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
Class ScreenMine(Screen):
    def pas (self):
      Pass

Class Myapp(App):
    def build (self):
      self.title="Myapp"

Myapp().run()
```

File .kv

```
ScreenMine
   BoxLayout:
     
     TextInput:
       id:ti
```

What I want is to format the speech in Arabic while writing inside the TextInput

Is Sajid an answer to this thing or is this difficult